# Webpack Module RefrenceError module is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, module-pattern

I'm tyring to bundle some modules using webpack2.  The modules are written using common module patterns (not CommonJS or AMD).

```
// in spUtil.js
var spUtil = (function(){
  var sp={};
  /* build some helper functions to set up urls and rest queries for sharepoint */
  return sp;
})();


// in listcrud.js
var listCrud=(function(){
  lc={};
  /* build some functions that get data from sharepoint lists */
  return lc;
})();

// in util.js
require("exports-loader?spUtil!./spUtil.js");
require("exports-loader?listCrud!./listcrud.js");
var util=(function(spUtil,listCrud){
  ut={};
  /* build some functions that query data from sharepoint */
  return ut;
})($,spUtil,listCrud);

// in myModule.js
var myModule=(function($,util){
  my={};
  /* build a view of some SP data */
  return my;
})($,util);
```

However I get an error while webpack tries to load the bundle;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: spUtil is not defined
    at Object.$.ajax.url (dashboard.bundle.js:389)
    at __webpack_require__ (dashboard.bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (dashboard.bundle.js:1076)
    at __webpack_require__ (dashboard.bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (dashboard.bundle.js:813)
    at __webpack_require__ (dashboard.bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (dashboard.bundle.js:1729)
    at __webpack_require__ (dashboard.bundle.js:20)
    at dashboard.bundle.js:66
    at dashboard.bundle.js:69
```

Webpack builds something like this:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(2);
__webpack_require__(1);
var util =(function($,spUtil,listCrud){
....
})($,sqUtil,listCrud);

/* 4 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(0);
var myModule=(function($,util){
  var my={};
  .....
  return my;
})($,util);
```

Where module 2 is spUtil and module 1 is listCrud.  Stepping through the dev tools debugger - spUtil is loaded, listCrud has already been 'installed' by webpack this function is called:

```
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error I was missing one key component.  Declaring the variable in in the module for it to use.

```
var spUtil = require('...spUtil.js');
var listCrud = require('...listcrud.js');
```